# Transforming a 3d point to a 2d plane then back again to a 3d point

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations, 3d

For 3d software, in the code, I'm changing a 3d point to a 2d point on a 2d plane, which represents a screen view, with the following method:

$x, y, z$ = given point in the 3d system.

$(X_u, Y_u, Z_u)$ = The transform for the 2d view plane Y-direction/upwards vector relative to the 3d system.

$(X_r, Y_r, Z_r)$ = The transform for the 2d view plane X-direction/rightwards vector relative to the 3d system.

View plane values: $x_1, y_1, z_1$

Equations:

$$x_1 = X_r x + Y_r y + Z_r z$$

$$y_1 = X_u x + Y_u y + Z_u z$$

$$z_1 = 0$$ 
Note that the software still tracks $z_1$ even though it always equals $0$

Now, I need to determine how to reverse this and determine the 3d point $x, y, z$. But I do not have the original 3d point. I do have values for:

The transforms for the 2d plane: $(X_u, Y_u, Z_u)$ and $(X_r, Y_r, Z_r)$

I, of course, have: $x_1, y_1, z_1$

I also happen to have the 3d x, y, z (say, $x_2$, $y_2$, $z_2$) values for a second point on the 2d plane (being the 3d values, this point has not been transformed, just like $x, y, z$ have not been transformed) The second point might be useful because $z_1$ was made to equal $0$. Though, please note, for my purposes, it should be okay if we pretend $$z_1 = 0$$ by way of a transform, so when it is reversed, the 3d point will actually lie on the 2d plane.

How can this be done?

Comment: It can't be done with the information you gave. There is an entire line in your 3d space that gets projected onto the same point $(x_1,y_1,0).$ Unless there is some special relationship between the second 3d point and the first one that you've forgotten to mention, that point does not give you any clue about which of many possible points got projected to $(x_1,y_1,0).$

Comment: Look at it this way: what you're asking is like taking a single photograph of the night sky, pointing at a particular star, and asking how far away it is. I can give you the complete information about another star in the photograph (including distance, which gives you complete 3d coordinates for that star), even give you distances to a hundred other stars in the same photo, and you still won't know the distance to the first star.

Comment: What if I had the value for $z_2$? Which, oddly, I should, because I have a second point that lies on the 2d plane but which is expressed in the 3d coordinate system.

Comment: I'm more concerned with transforming $x_1$, and $y_1$ back to their original x,y,z values. See my edited version, which indicates we can use $z_1 = 0$ when we transform it back.

Comment: None of this is any good. I'm sorry. This is a classic problem of reconstructing 3d data from a 2d image. If you had two different projections of the original point, or if you had some other information such as the distance between the two points in their original 3d coordinates, you might have something. But you need **something** that is uniquely about the original 3d point that cannot be true of any other point and is more than just the projected $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ coordinates.

Comment: @ David. Put it this way. For my purposes, $z$ and $z_1$ is always on the 2d plane. It's not a star somewhere out there. So, I have a point on a plane, I have the transformations that describe the plane relative to the 3d system, and I have a second point that can be thought of like an origin for the 2d plane, which is offset from the 3d system origin. Seems like I should have plenty of info here. No?

Comment: I looked at my software. I also have the transform for the view direction (the direction towards the viewer). If that helps.

Comment: I've created a new question, in light of having the third transform here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3560243/573646

Comment: In your revised question, if the image of a three-dimensional object is a three-dimensional object that does not fit into any plane, then you can probably recover the data, because you have not put all the points onto a single 2d plane. But then what is a "viewing plane" and why do you even mention it?

Comment: viewing plane is what it is called in the software. It's a 2d representation of a 3d point in a matrix oriented to be relative to the viewing plane. Not sure that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pure 3D rotation matrix is [orthonormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix),
$$\mathbf{R} = \left[ \begin{matrix} \hat{e}_1 & \hat{e}_2 & \hat{e}_3 \end{matrix} \right ] = \left [ \begin{matrix}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \\ y_1 & y_2 & y_3 \\ z_1 & z_2 & z_3 \end{matrix} \right ]$$
where the three (column) vectors form the [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)):
$$\begin{array}{lll}
\hat{e}_1\cdot\hat{e}_1 = 1, ~ & \hat{e}_1\times\hat{e}_1 = 0 \\
\hat{e}_1\cdot\hat{e}_2 = 0, ~ & \hat{e}_1\times\hat{e}_2 = \hat{e}_3 \\
\hat{e}_1\cdot\hat{e}_3 = 0, ~ & \hat{e}_1\times\hat{e}_3 = -\hat{e}_2 \\
\hat{e}_2\cdot\hat{e}_1 = 0, ~ & \hat{e}_2\times\hat{e}_1 = -\hat{e}_3 \\
\hat{e}_2\cdot\hat{e}_2 = 1, ~ & \hat{e}_2\times\hat{e}_2 = 0  \\
\hat{e}_2\cdot\hat{e}_3 = 0, ~ & \hat{e}_2\times\hat{e}_3 = \hat{e}_1 \\
\hat{e}_3\cdot\hat{e}_1 = 0, ~ & \hat{e}_3\times\hat{e}_1 = \hat{e}_2 \\
\hat{e}_3\cdot\hat{e}_2 = 0, ~ & \hat{e}_3\times\hat{e}_2 = -\hat{e}_1 \\
\hat{e}_3\cdot\hat{e}_3 = 1, ~ & \hat{e}_3\times\hat{e}_3 = 0 \\
\end{array}$$
The nice property of such matrices is that their inverse is their transpose:
$$\mathbf{R}^{-1} = \mathbf{R}^{T} = \left [ \begin{matrix}
x_1 & y_1 & z_1 \\ x_2 & y_2 & z_2 \\ x_3 & y_3 & z_3 \end{matrix} \right ]$$
which is also an orthonormal matrix itself.  So, to reverse a pure rotation, you just apply the transpose of the matrix:
$$\vec{a} = \mathbf{R}\vec{b} \quad \iff \quad \vec{b} = \mathbf{R}^{T} \vec{a}$$

---

The problem with recovering 3D position from a 2D image is that the third component (depth or distance or $z$) is unknown.  This means that each 2D point can be only converted to a *line*, perpendicular to the original 2D plane, passing through the point on that 2D plane.

When the same object is viewed from two different angles, *and each point can be identified separately*, the depth information can be obtained from the intersection of those two lines.  This is also called stereoscopic vision or [stereopsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereopsis), and is how [depth perception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_perception) works in us humans.
A number of visual tricks rely on tricking the brain to consider two separate points, each seen by a separate eye, as the same one, and thus constructing an incorrect perception (of depth in particular).

Human depth perception is also aided by perceiving edges and overlaps, and the brain automatically assigning "depth" to each detail based on these cues.  There are complex computer programs that do this also, that can recover some/enough depth information from a single photograph (things like rooms/walls, tables, rectangular objects; but not very well from things like faces or softly curving objects) to reproduce a 3D analog of that picture, but the mathematics and perception modeling is rather complex, and definitely not something one can explain, or even start to explain, in a StackExchange answer.