# Transform a 3d point to a coordinate system relative to a viewing plane, and transform it back to its original coordinate system

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations, 3d

For 3d software, in the code, I'm changing a 3d point from a stable coordinate system to a coordinate system that is relative to the screen view, using the following method:

$x, y, z$ = given point in the 3d system.

$(X_u, Y_u, Z_u)$ = The transform for the 2d view plane Y-direction/upwards vector relative to the 3d system.

$(X_r, Y_r, Z_r)$ = The transform for the 2d view plane X-direction/rightwards vector relative to the 3d system.

$(X_s, Y_s, Z_s)$ = The transform for the 2d view plane Z-direction/towards the viewing screen relative to the 3d system.

View plane values: $x_1, y_1, z_1$

Equations:

$$x_1 = X_r x + Y_r y + Z_r z$$

$$y_1 = X_u x + Y_u y + Z_u z$$

$$z_1 = X_s x + Y_s y + Z_s z$$

Note that the point is still in 3d space, it's just that its points are now measured relative to the viewing plane.

The problem I've come across is that I need to take $x_1, y_1, z_1$ and turn it back into $x, y, z$ without knowing the values of $x, y, z$, of course. I do have the transformations above and $x_1, y_1, z_1$.

What equations can I use to transform the point back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your equations as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\y_1\\z_1
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
X_r&Y_r&Z_r\\
X_u&Y_u&Z_u\\
X_s&Y_s&Z_s
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so, if the matrix is invertible, we have:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
X_r&Y_r&Z_r\\
X_u&Y_u&Z_u\\
X_s&Y_s&Z_s
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\y_1\\z_1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: @ Emilio, this is great, but I'm a bit rusty on turning transforms into usable algebraic equations in code. I suppose I could search for an API to handle it for me, but it would be much more user-friendly in basic algebra. If possible.

Comment: Searching on the web for ''inverse matrix'' you can find a lot of examples. The first I encounter is https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-inverse-minors-cofactors-adjugate.html

Comment: No. It is not so simple! You  can see here another way to solve your linear system : https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra-home/alg-system-of-equations/alg-systems-with-three-variables/v/systems-of-three-variables-2

Comment: Here you have the general formula for the in verse matrix: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixInverse.html

Comment: O.K., thanks. It's been a while since i've inverted a matrix. Maybe the software API will have a way to simplify it. Either way, I'll need to figure this out.